# How to add "Checkbox" information/meta fields in Content Profile page in Oracle UCM?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-ucm

My client has a special request, they want me to add checkbox in my content profile page in Oracle UCM. I know there's only 6 types of fields are there but checkbox is not one of them. Is it even possible to add checkbox information/meta field in content profile page?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, check boxes are not used in the Content Server UI.  If they are, it's usually done in a way where the checkbox just executes JavaScript to populate a hidden meta element.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following custom dynamichtml include *std_checkbox_field* for the field.

This is the Oracle code for *std_checkbox_field*:

```
<@dynamichtml std_checkbox_field@>
  <$if checkboxFieldName$><$tempFieldName = fieldName, fieldName = checkboxFieldName$><$endif$>
  <$if checkboxFieldCaption$><$fieldCaption = checkboxFieldCaption$><$endif$>
  <$exec inc("compute_std_field_overrides")$>
  <$if not isFieldExcluded$>
    <$exec inc("compute_std_checkbox_includes")$>
    <$inc(fieldInclude)$>
  <$endif$>
  <$if checkboxFieldName$><$fieldName = tempFieldName$><$endif$>
  <$exec inc("std_field_cleanup")$>
<@end@>
```